# Angular json page refresh using $route.reload() not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an angular app and i am trying to achieve a refresh of the page. I am trying the `$route.reload()` as suggested in many posts. But i am not able to get it to work. Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('StudentProgram', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'jsonService']);

        app.controller('mycontroller', function($route, RequirementsService, DegreesService, DegreeCategoriesService, DetailsService, ProgramsService, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {
          ProgramsService.getItems(function(data){
        $scope.programs  = data;
        console.log(data);
      });

      $scope.$route = $route;
      //$scope.programs=ProgramsService.query();

      DegreeCategoriesService.query(function(data){
        $scope.degreecategories = data;
        console.log(data);
      });

      DetailsService.query(function(data){
        $scope.details = data;
        console.log(data);
      });

      RequirementsService.getRequirements(function(data){
        $scope.requirements = data;
        console.log(data);
      });

          $scope.addDegree = function(degree) {
            var variablesToSend =   {
                                        "student": 2773951,
                                        "credits_completed": 0, 
                                        "academic_program_gpa": 0, 
                                        "primary_program": false,
                                        "academic_program": {
                                            "id": degree.id,
                                            "acad_program_category": degree.acad_program_category,
                                            "acad_program_type": degree.acad_program_type,
                                            "program_title": degree.program_title, 
                                            "required_credits": degree.required_credits, 
                                            "min_gpa": degree.min_gpa, 
                                            "description": "description of the course", 
                                            "colleges": degree.colleges
                                        }
                                    }
            $http.post('/api/studentacademicprogram/', variablesToSend).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                alert('post added');
                $route.reload();
            }, function(response){
                console.log(response);
                alert('post not added');
            });
          };
```

Here is the div where i am accessing the function:

```
<div ng-show="display.academicdegrees" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                <div class="panel panel-warning list-group list-unstyled" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#panelcategory" data-offset="0" style="max-height:400px;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        {% verbatim %}
                        <h3 class="panel-title">{{DegreeCategory}}</h3>
                        {% endverbatim %}
                    </div>
                    <li ng-repeat="degree in degrees" class="list-group-item">
                        {% verbatim %}<strong>{{degree.program_title}}</strong>{% endverbatim %}
                        <p>{% verbatim %}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{degree.description}}</p>
                        <span ng-repeat="college in degree.colleges">
                            <i><img ng-src="/static/icons/{{college}}.png" /></i>
                        </span>{% endverbatim %}
                        <span class="pull-right btn btn-success" ng-click="addDegree(degree)">Add</span>
                    </li>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Where am i making the error? The page is refreshing when i hit the refresh button but it does not happen when i call the function.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: And paste your routeProvider.

Comment: i am not getting any error. do i need to give any url in the $route.reload()?

Comment: what do you mean you are not getting any error? you said Chrome is throwing me an error

Comment: I am sorry i edited the question improperly. That was an error i got around for not including the anular-routes.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem and I have not been able to find any solution, so I have used a alternative hack of redirecting to the same page using $location. Ofcourse I would like to know a real solution but this is how I have used a makeshift hack-

```
$window.location.href='http://yoursite.com'
```

Will keep looking for something better. Do not forget to inject $location into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true });
```

or this

```
$state.go($state.$current, null, { reload: true });
```